# How can I improve the font rendering of Swing Java applications under Ubuntu?

Tags: java, fonts

Some Swing-Java programs in Ubuntu look very ugly because of their font.

What's wrong with the fonts? Is there any way to fix the aliasing?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot so that we can get a better idea of what's wrong.

Comment: I cannot provide a solution but I suffer from the same problem and created two screenshots demonstrating it. To me it looks like the subpixel rendering produces way too strong color fringes around the letters. Note: if your display has a different subpixel order than mine or does not have subpixels at all, the font rendering may look totally off to you. - [Screenshot of Arduino IDE with ugly fonts](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KX0Nj.png)
- [Screenshot of JabRef with ugly fonts](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TNqRh.png) *Meta: Annoyingly, Ask Ubuntu/SE does not allow me to add this note as a comment to t